# PHP inserting some weird character in database. like â€“ instead of this –

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, pdo

`UPDATE Tasks SET taskname='Character  – – ' WHERE taskguid='D782BA07-9B42-46BB-B4C1-3C6E844880F5`'

if I am running this query using SQL server management studio then everything looks normal but if I am executing this query in PHP using PDO then it inserting some wired characters like

```
character â€“ â€“
```

I know something is missing but have no idea. why its happening?

I am using

```
PHP (Version 5.3.8)
PDO_ODBC (ODBC Connection Pooling Enabled, strict matching)
IIS 7 (using FastCGI)
Window server 2008R2
SQL SEVER 2008
```

**EDIT**

I got some more characters.

```
'â€™' = '’'
'â€˜' = '‘'
'â€”' = '–'
'â€¢' = '-'
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's something to do with character encoding in the database. I'm not familiar with SQL Server, but I have seen something similar with MySQL related to the encoding set for a table.

Comment: Or maybe when you post the data to the processing script it encode de value...or maybe in the pdo operation

Comment: @Kryten I saw lots of SO question but they didnt work with MSSQL.

Comment: @RiteshChandora yeah, probably lots of people have seen this with MySQL. I added the `sql-server` tag to your question so it might show up for someone with more experience with SQL Server.

Comment: Can someone explain me the reason for downvote..

Comment: @RiteshChandora don't know, I upvoted to counter... good question :)

Comment: @RobertRozas I am direct executing the query. no pre processing.

Comment: What character are those dashes supposed to be?

Comment: @VBCPP  they are just simple ascii character.

Comment: If what you posted is actual code, not just a fabricated example, then no they're not. a search for "dash converted to â€“" will give you some examples

Answer (score 1):

`â€“` is clear evidence of UTF-8 damage, i.e. a multibyte character sequence in UTF-8 is being reinterpreted as another encoding.  The simplest fix is to make sure everything is using UTF-8, including your database connection, user input, string literals, etc.  Note that UTF-8 is not the default encoding on Windows, so you might need to be explicit in various places.

Comment: yes its clear evidence of UTF-8 Damage.. do you know how to fix this?

Comment: yep, he even tells you how: `make sure everything is using UTF-8, including your database connection, user input, string literals, etc.` meaning you have to set the charset when you establish the PDO connection, maybe in the script which runs the data, probably in the user input script as well is there is any

Answer (score -1):

You might use the wrong charset.

Try this: 
(Header should be at the top of the code)

```
<?php
   header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
```

And add this after connecting to MySQL:

```
<?php
    mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
?>
```

Comment: You have to SET NAMES every time you work with your MSSQL stuff. Have a look at the Table collation and set it to UTF-8 as well. And then repair your values.

Comment: @zerophreak please don't suggest `mysql_*` use ever again, especially when people specify they are using PDO and superespecially because it is deprecated.